An identity with quaternions
Let $A$ be a quaternion such that $|A|=1$.
For any quaternion $q$, define a vector
$$
\vec n(q) := \left(\rule{0pt}{5mm}\mathrm{Re}(\bar q A i \bar A),\ \mathrm{Re}(\bar qAj\bar A),\ \mathrm{Re}(\bar q A k A)\right)\ \in\ \mathbb{R}^3
$$
I am trying to prove that the vectors
$$
\vec n(i),\ \vec n(j),\ \vec n(k)
$$
are orthonormal with respect to the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^3$.
I know I could just expand everything and prove this very explicitly, and in fact I did that.
However, the calculations seemed to depend on some magical cancelations which made me suspect that this should hold for a deeper reason.

$\mathrm{Re}(\bar vw) = v\cdot w$ when vectors $v,w$ are interpreted as imaginary quaternions. The expression $Av\bar A$ is always imaginary when $v$ is imaginary, and we only care about imaginary inputs to $\vec n$, so we may write
$$
  \vec n(v) = [v\cdot(Ai\bar A)]i + [v\cdot(Aj\bar A)]j + [v\cdot(Ak\bar A)]k.
$$
The adjoint of a linear transformation $L$ is the unique map $L'$ such that
$$
  v\cdot L(w) = L'(v)\cdot w.
$$
The map $w\mapsto Aw\bar A$ is a rotation, and so its adjoint is its inverse $w \mapsto \bar AwA$. Thus
$$
  \vec n(v) = [(\bar AvA)\cdot i]i + [(\bar AvA)\cdot j]j + [(\bar AvA)\cdot k]k = \bar AvA.
$$
Thus $\vec n$ is just the inverse of the rotation represented by $A$, and rotations preserve orthonormality, so $\vec n(i),\vec n(j),\vec n(k)$ are orthonormal.
